# grep first n and last n characters from a line in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, cut

I have a log file which looks like:

```
Mar 23 08:20:23 New file got created in sec: 235
Mar 23 08:21:45 New file got created in sec: 127
Mar 23 08:22:34 New file got created in sec: 875
Mar 23 08:25:46 New file got created in sec: 322
Mar 23 08:26:12 New file got created in sec: 639
```

I need the output to look like:

```
Mar 23 08:20:23 : 235
Mar 23 08:21:45 : 127
Mar 23 08:22:34 : 875
Mar 23 08:25:46 : 322
Mar 23 08:26:12 : 639
```

What I am able to do is just grep either first part or the last part of the line. I am not able to put the two together. How can I get the desired output from my input?

Comment: @StephenRauch what if the middle content of the line is not same always?

Comment: @StephenRauch Yes the length is always the same.

Comment: I updated my answer based on knowing the length will be the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,":",$NF}' logfile
```

Comment: It is better to use `$NF` instead of  `$10` to make it working as requested without dependency on the middle part. `NF` refers to the number of fields (10 in this case).

Comment: @pabouk that would be best ! i have changed it as per your suggestion...

Comment: It's also possible to use `$(NF - 1)` to get the penultimate field, etc.

Comment: works exactly I wanted it to.

Comment: @IAmAndroid I'm glad ..... Keep scripting ....

Answer (score 16):

You can use cut as:

**Command:**

```
cut --complement -c17-43 file1.txt
```

**Output:**

```
Mar 23 08:20:23 : 235
Mar 23 08:21:45 : 127
Mar 23 08:22:34 : 875
Mar 23 08:25:46 : 322
Mar 23 08:26:12 : 639
```

Comment: Note that this may fail when the day of the month is a single digit, depending on whether it is zero-padded.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -r "s/^(.{15} ?).*(.{5})$/\1\2/" logfile
```

Per suggestions, I have made the first pattern accommodate single-digit days which may not be zero-padded, and use `.*` for the middle pattern to be more flexible.

Comment: what if the middle content of the line is not same always?

Comment: It is much better to use `.*` instead of  `.{27}` and anchor to the start and end of the line using `^` and `$` (but it should work without the anchors too) otherwise you are uselessly depending on the length of the middle part.

Comment: This will fail if single-digit days aren't zero-padded.

Comment: Thanks all, I have updated the patterns to accommodate your suggestions and concerns.

Answer (score 4):

In awk, it's something like this. Very simple.

```
[zee@dev-instance temp]$ cat file1.txt 
Mar 23 08:20:23 New file got created in sec: 235
Mar 23 08:21:45 New file got created in sec: 127
Mar 23 08:22:34 New file got created in sec: 875
Mar 23 08:25:46 New file got created in sec: 322
Mar 23 08:26:12 New file got created in sec: 639
[zee@dev-instance temp]$ awk -F" " '{ print $1" "$2" "$3" : "$10 }'<file1.txt 
Mar 23 08:20:23 : 235
Mar 23 08:21:45 : 127
Mar 23 08:22:34 : 875
Mar 23 08:25:46 : 322
Mar 23 08:26:12 : 639
[zee@dev-instance temp]$
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.\{4\}\).*\(.\{4\}\)$/\1 \2/'
```

(You can figure out the I/O redirection or give filename, etc.  See sed(1) for more invocation info.)

Here, I have chosen the number of characters to be exactly 4, but you could substitute any number(s) you like.  Note that the first and last number of characters can even be different:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.\{5\}\).*\(.\{2\}\)$/\1 \2/'
```

This would return the first 5 characters and last 2 characters of each line.  I'll leave it to you to figure out how to parameterize this further.

Also, note that I have chosen sed(1) rather than grep(1) (or one of its variants).  I know that this may not be quite what you want as you did ask for a grep regex, not a sed regex.

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this

`cut -c1-15 logfile > file;`

`cut -c44- logfile > file1;`

`paste file file1 > logfilenew;`

`rm file file1;`

`cat logfilenew`

output will store in the logfilenew.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -F '' -lane 'print @F[0..15, -5..-1]' yourfile
```

## Explanation

`-F ''` => split the line into individual characters, IOW, all fields are 1-char thick.

`-l` => `ORS=\n`

`-a` => `@F array holds the fields, e.g., $F[15] => holds the 16-th character`

`-n` => `don't print unless specifically asked to`

`@F[0..15, -5..-1]` => is a slice of the array `@F` with the first 16 characters, and the last 5 characters, something along the lines of `cut`

Comment: Err, the question only shows 10 columns, so what would `$F[15]` be selecting?

Comment: I guess some explanation would be welcomed. OP might want to adapt command to fit other need, of file format change.

Comment: You need to realize that the columns are all 1-character wide, due to the `-F` option being supplied with nothing. Better to say: `-F ''` I guess to make the intent unambiguous.